# Will the .Net Entity Framework work with a .mdb?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ms-access

Can use a .mdb file as the data source for an Entity Framework model using the Microsoft Jet OLEDB data provider? If so, how will I be limited? No stored procedures, for example.

Comment: Every time you use Microsoft Access in a production application, God kills a kitten.

Comment: @George Stocker: cheap shot, the type of thing that is conventional wisdom among those too ignorant or lazy to use Jet/ACE properly.

Comment: Jet and Access have their purpose. There is nothing better than Access for rapidly deploying a single user relational database. Using sql server express and a winforms/wpf front end for building a cd catalog is tremendous overkill for a one off project.

Comment: @Ryan Michela: Using 'relational database' for a single user app is probably overkill (not that the Access Database Engine is anything like truly relational).

Comment: It's "relational" enough to track my cd catalog.

Comment: Did you get that to work? Does entity framework connect to .mdb?

Comment: @Saher. I never got entity framework to connect to an access database. We settled on using SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a Entity Framework Expert, but seems to be not working with MS Access.